# obspy read wav file unknown format

Tags: stream, format, wav, obspy

I try to reproduce the given example [obspy example](https://docs.obspy.org/packages/obspy.io.wav.html#module-obspy.io.wav) in order to read a wav, unfortunately even with the same code as written in the example, I raise an error:

the wav exemple file can be downloaded from here:
[download 3cssan.near.8.1.RNON.wav](https://examples.obspy.org/)

```
from obspy import read
read("3cssan.near.8.1.RNON.wav")
[...]
TypeError: Unknown format for file 3cssan.near.8.1.RNON.wav
```

I would be very grateful if you have any suggestion to fix this problem
I would like to use obspy because I would like to continue my analysis with using a code implemented with obspy

Best regards

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the both WAV files that are available on the Obspy's website, are possible to be read without any problems.

In your case, I would suggest to define format you want to read in the read method:

```
from obspy import read
read("3cssan.near.8.1.RNON.wav", format="wav")
```

If this still won't work, I suggest redownloading the test file as it might be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

```
from obspy import read 
st = read("/path/to/3cssan.near.8.1.RNON.wav", format="wav")
print(st) 
st.plot();
```

hope this could help you
https://docs.obspy.org/archive/1.2.0/packages/obspy.io.wav.html